# Anylogic - placing resources on GIS map

Tags: dictionary, resources, gis, anylogic, agent

I have a GIS map on main and I have a population of Suppliers on main.  Each Supplier has it's own fleet of delivery vehicles which are modelled as a ResourcePool of type DeliveryTruck inside the Supplier agent.  I am able to place the Suppliers on the GIS map at the correct locations as defined by longitude and latitude.
In the Properties of the DeliveryTruck ResourcePool I call unit.setLocation(this) in the "On new unit" action however when I query the location of the DeliveryTrucks (getLongitude(), getLatitude()) the DeliveryTrucks are at 0,0 rather than the long/lat of the Supplier they belong to.

Even after I move the trucks to a location on the GIS map using moveTo(longitude, latitude) and query the trucks location on arrival, it still returns 0,0.

I'm guessing it has something to do with making sure the trucks are in the GISMap environment on main but as the ResourcePool for the DeliveryTrucks is within the Supplier it is not obvious how I get them into the GIS map on main.

Any ideas?